# Delta function constraint as Lagrange multiplier in SYK model calculation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, dirac-delta-distributions

In eq. (112) of [these lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.08482.pdf) the author is introducing a 1 into an integral in the following way

[image]

This looks like an integral representation of the delta function $\delta(x)\sim \int dy\, e^{i x y}$, but I am confused by the fact that the factor in the exponential function seems to be not $i$ but instead $-\frac{1}{2}$. The author comments something about $\Sigma$ being a Lagrange multiplier enforcing the delta function constraint, which I have never seen being done like that before.

> Maybe someone here can explain in a few more details and a bit more rigor how the transformation of delta functions to Lagrange multipliers works?

Comment: Similar question on Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2829562/11127

Comment: In the path integral of $\Sigma$ field, one needs to assume a proper contour, e.g. going from -i $\infty$ to +i$\infty$. One puzzling thing is that the physical saddles of $(G,\Sigma)$ are real, but there is no contradiction.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is also asked on Math.SE.